# PowerShell can't connect to Windows IoT

Tags: windows, windows-iot, pi-2, powershell

I am following the instructions from [Using PowerShell to connect and configure a device running Windows 10 IoT Core](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/PowerShell.htm) to access my Raspberry Pi 2 with Windows 10 IoT via PowerShell.

```
PS C:\> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName minwinpc -Credential minwinpc\Administrator
```

This then opens a window where I enter the default password.

Then after about two minutes, it fails with

```
Enter-PSSession : Processing data from remote server minwinpc failed with the following error message: The WinRM
client cannot process the request because the server name cannot be resolved. For more information, see the
about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enter-PSSession -ComputerName minwinpc -Credential minwinpc\Administrator
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (minwinpc:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
```

The Raspberry Pi 2 is, of course, up and running and I can access the website at http://minwinpc:8080

The development PC has windows 8.1 and is in the same subnet as the Raspberry Pi 2.

I already tried all the steps with the IP address instead of the hostname, but it gives the same error.

Comment: can you try adding the `-Port` flag and adding the port (check firewall settings on your machine(s) and router, sometimes these things are set to disallow remote access.)

Comment: Are you using x86 powershell ? I encountered similar problem when using x64 powershell, but using x86 didn't show the issue.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: nope, still stuck.

Comment: For anyone coming across this issue belatedly now, install and use the "Windows IoT Core Dashboard".  It can list IoT-Core devices running locally and with a right click give you direct access, subject to a login, via Shares, Powershell etc

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

I visited this link - [Setting up Windows 10 for IoT on your Raspberry Pi 2](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SettingUpWindows10ForIoTOnYourRaspberryPi2.aspx) - and cut/paste code to connect from there on to the powershell - it connected fine.

```
net start WinRM
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value MINWINPC
remove-module psreadline -force
Enter-PsSession -ComputerName MINWINPC -Credential MINWINPC\Administrator
```

Only difference was the `remove-module psreadline -force` line.

Wondering if that caused issues - [How can I get an interactive login with Windows 10 IoT Core running on a Raspberry Pi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30134515/how-can-i-get-an-interactive-login-with-win10-iot-core-running-on-a-raspberry-pi)

Comment: I guess (not using Windows or PowerShell) it is connecting using SSL (not sure since isn't mentioned anywhere) and if so there's a certificate/host check, an you're using a *full uppercase* host name for `TrustedHosts`, this *could* make the difference

Comment: thanks, i tried that additional line, but it gives me this error: `remove-module : No modules were removed. Verify that the specification of modules to remove is correct and those modules exist in the runspace.`

Answer (score 1):

I think Alex is Correct 
I closed and start power shell again and only difference I did was set the PC name all lower case (as its actual named)

```
net start WinRM
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value minwinpc
Enter-PsSession -ComputerName minwinpc -Credential minwinpc\Administrator
```

Did not use this line

```
remove-module psreadline -force
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I reformatted my SD card(using Diskpart) and then reinstalled the IoT core OS and ran Powershell and this time I didn't perform the code line: `remove-module psreadline -force` 
after it when I booted my device on the core watcher and deployed a solution to it, It works just fine and Powershell works as well after the deployment of the first program.